# Intent filter that registers for a file extension receives 2 file protocols in the URI

Tags: android

The app registers for a certain file extension ".foo", commonly located at the root of what the Android APIs call 'External Storage', but the Google File Explorer calls 'Internal Storage'.

However, when I click on the file I am receiving a strange URI:

> file:///1/file%3A/storage/emulated/0/config.foo

It leads to a file not found exception when I try to do an `OpenInputStream` on it:

> /1/file:/storage/emulated/0/config.foo: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory)

The manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Can receive a transfer file and decrypt it -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foo"/>
        <data android:host="*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

In the case I am testing, the user has accepted the runtime permissions via the standard Android permission dialogue:

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
}
```

The source code that fails with a `FileNotFound` exception:

```
Uri fileUri = getIntent().getData();
InputStream fis = appContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
```

Experiments:

1: Try open the file directly to see if we have access:

```
String[] parts = fileUri.toString().split("%3A");
String path = parts[1];
File file = new File(path);
if (file.exists()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Exists");
}
```

2: Test that `openInputStream` can open the file:

```
InputStream fis = appContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/config.foo"));
```

Experiments 1 and 2 both succeed.

I believe this code worked on older versions of Android. The device I am testing it on now is an Android One device running Android 10.

I realise that Google have changed direction with regards to the file system and all code regarding external storage needs to be rewritten. However, I am  trying to find a temporary solution for this problem.

Does anyone know why it is adding the "file" protocol twice to the URI when the file is tapped from the Google file explorer? I would be grateful for any speculation or things to try. Thanks!

[image]

Version:
[image]

Comment: The path you get and should use is of course /storage/emulated/0/config.foo. Remove the garbage first.

Comment: @blackapps Yes...It seems like it may be a defect with the built-in file manager.